# Cortana skill not working on Windows 10 or iOS

Tags: windows-10, bots, cortana, azure-bot-service, cortana-skills-kit

I have added a Cortana skill using Microsoft Bot Framework. My invocation phrase is "My Skill". When I tried to talk to Cortana in iOS or Windows, it doesn't invoke the skill. Instead, it keep directing me to Bing results. Here are the sentences I talked to Cortana:

- Start My Skill
- Ask My Skill to
- Tell My Skill that

Anyone advices?

Comment: can anyone down vote give a suggestion why? Appreciate

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I guess it's because you are basically missing the [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we need in order to analyze the issue.

Comment: thanks mate. i updated a bit more info, and please feel free to update my post or comment

Comment: The example needs to have code. Please include the settings file where you added the voice commands and then the code being called by Cortana when the command itself has been given by the user (it's been a long time since I worked with it, if there's anything else involved in it, please include it).

Comment: I see, the work we are doing is new stuff. Because Microsoft just added Cortana support for botframework like one week ago. And you don't need to have any code when adding skill using bot. here is a link mate. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/debug-bots-cortana-skill-invoke#register-your-bot

Comment: Have you enabled the Cortana channel on the Bot?

Comment: Yes mate, i have enabled that. The Bot framework portal says the Cortana portal is running. And I believe I don't have click "Publish to the world" button if i just want to test that myself, right?

Comment: To those thinking this is not a coding related problem. This is question is almost like how to fix a Visual Studio configuration issue. it is not to do with coding but it is something developers will care when they try to apply their bot onto Cortana.   please suggest a recommended forum I should use first. Thanks heaps

Comment: Are you signed into Cortana using the same email account that you use to sign into the bot framework portal? To check in Cortana, go to, Notebook -> About me.

Comment: Yes, and may I know what you mean by Notebook?

Comment: Do I have to pay the one off individual developer fee to in order to get the invocation?

Comment: No, you don't need to pay anything to create and release Cortana skills. If you find yourself at a place to pay to access a developer portal, you likely ended up at the Windows app developer portal.

Comment: In Cortana there is a Notebook button. In Windows it is below the "House" button. It kind of looks like an image or a book icon. If you press the "three line" button it will expand the button in include their names.

Comment: Yes mate, when I click About me, it is showing my correct Microsoft Account.

Comment: Having a similar problem to this. I created the skill and can access it, but none of my other collegues can.

Comment: To make others access it, are their names added into a list in the skill deployed user list in Cortana dev centre? And then they will get a link. One of my team mate got this working. And he has to change all the locale on the of to en-us and location us. Hope that helps

Comment: Currently Cortana Skills are only available in the United States, locale en-us. [*Source: Near the bottom of the FAQ*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills-faq)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One friend fixed this issue, so at the moment Cortana only supports English(United States). To fix it, go to Cortana setting (please note , not the OS language setting) -> In Language, select English (United States). And it should work, please note for apps on the phone, a restart will be needed.

Comment: You saved my life. This is still an issue on en-GB machines.

Answer (score 2):

You might find a better success rate for skill invocation by following the [Cortana Invocation Name Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/cortana-invocation-guidelines). More specifically, the docs have a short (but helpful) section on [Invocation Name Recommendations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/cortana-invocation-guidelines#invocation-name-recommendations).

Following this, the emphasis and intonation you place on the skill invocation name will also help determine if your skill activates, or if you end up with a Bing search for, "*ask my skill...*"

Answer (score 0):

I added myself to the Test Group and then joined the group using the Group Access URL. Then it worked.

It also helped to use a very distinct invocation name.

[image]